# Getting all public constants from the main and nested classes

Tags: c#, recursion, reflection

I wrote this recursive function to get all constants from a class and its subclasses. Can it be simplified?

```
private static IEnumerable<FieldInfo> GetPublicConstants(Type type)
{
    var subtypes = type.GetNestedTypes(BindingFlags.Public);

    foreach (var subtype in subtypes)
    {
        foreach (var constant in GetPublicConstants(subtype))
        {
            yield return constant;
        }
    }

    var publicStaticFields = type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Public |
         BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy)
         .Where(fi => fi.IsLiteral && !fi.IsInitOnly);

    foreach (var fieldInfo in publicStaticFields)
    {
        yield return fieldInfo;
    }
}
```

For example, it would return 6 constants for the following class:

> ```
> public static class MyClass
> {
>     public const string AAA = "";
>
>     public static class A
>     {
>         public const string Aaaaa = "";
>
>         public static class AB
>         {
>             public const string ABaaa = "";
>         }
>     }
>
>     public static class B
>     {
>         public const string Baaa = "";
>         public const string Bbbb = "";
>     }
>
>     public static class C
>     {
>         public const string Caaa = "";
>     }
> }
> ```

What I don't like is the fact I'm having 2 loops where I yield return 1 item because of inability to yield return a list of items.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about this:

```
private static IEnumerable<FieldInfo> GetPublicConstants(Type type)
{
    return GetPublicClassConstants(type)
        .Concat(type.GetNestedTypes(BindingFlags.Public).SelectMany(GetPublicConstants));
}

private static IEnumerable<FieldInfo> GetPublicClassConstants(Type type)
{
    return type
        .GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy)
        .Where(fi => fi.IsLiteral && !fi.IsInitOnly);
}
```

OR, as I do enjoy playing PGA Pro Code Golf:

```
private static IEnumerable<FieldInfo> GetPublicConstants(Type type)
{
    return type
        .GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy)
        .Where(fi => fi.IsLiteral && !fi.IsInitOnly)
        .Concat(type.GetNestedTypes(BindingFlags.Public).SelectMany(GetPublicConstants));
}
```

Comment: sorry, didn't understand the PGA reference however 2nd solution is ace!

Comment: @Tsar "Professional Golfers Association" and code golf is the art/game of making the code as small as possible.